# Propagate changes to other storyboard languages

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, storyboard

I have a project with two localizations add. English and Spanish. My app has a main storyboard for iPhone and two storyboard, one for each languages that I select (english and spanish). When I change main storyboard only english storyboard is propagated the changes, never spanish storyboard is change unless I change spanish storyboard.

Everytime when I run the project on the device I must delete spanish localization and add spanish again. In this way the spanish storyboard is a exact copy of main storyboard.

How do I can propagate the changes automatically for spanish storyboard?

Comment: On simulator all works correctly, only the problem I have with iPhone developer device...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess there is no Apple-approved solution to this.  Here's another possible solution though:

#### Python Script

http://code.google.com/p/edim-mobile/source/browse/trunk/ios/IncrementalLocalization/localize.py

#### Demo Video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF1Rf02QvZQ.

Comment: I watched this video in the past, but I can't to implement this solution. The Python Script it seems that doesn't work in my project. May be I need add any reference or something like this... thanks for your answer!